# How to build collapse list (Codeigniter)

Tags: html, codeigniter

I want to build a collapse list and that list of data is from my database. That's why i used `foreach($mother->result() as $row)`. Each collapse data shown on the browser has its own sub list again which have `Panel Body` and `Panel Footer`. What i got from these code on the browser was when i clicked other collapse data buttons instead of first button, it also showed me the first sub list of first collapse data button.

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Collapsible Panel</h2>
  <p>Click on the collapsible panel to open and close it.</p>
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">

        <?php
        $mother = $this->db->query("SELECT Description,ChildNode from mrpreport.report where MotherNode='MAIN'");
        foreach($mother->result() as $row) { 
        ?>

      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1"><?php echo $row->Description?></a>
        </h4>
      </div>

      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Panel Body</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
      </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1"><?php echo $row->Description?></a>
```

You can see your href point to id collapse1, instead of that, you should set `$i = 0` outside, then `echo $i++;` inside link element.
I hope it can help you.

Comment: If my answer is true, please accept it as your answer, thanks xD